# JQuery IF Statement not working MVC View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller

I have a MVC View where I have a webgrid. I am trying to set the back color of rows conditionally based on value of one of the columns. I have the following JQuery script that I am trying to use for that.

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('tbody tr').each(function (index) { //iterate over all table rows
            if (index > 0) {     //skip header
                var cellval = $(this).children('td:nth-child(7)').text();
                alert(cellval);
                if (cellval == 'Canceled') 
                {
                    alert('this is Canceled');
                    $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
                }

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I added the alert stmts to check the values Im comparing in the IF stmt. The first 
    alert(cellval)
is working and I am able to see the values correctly. However, When the value is 'Canceled'  the if stmt is not going into the block - meaning I do not see the 'This is canceled' alert nor is the back color set! 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
                @grid.GetHtml(
                    tableStyle: "webgrid-table",
                    headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
                    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
                    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
                    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-row-style",
                    htmlAttributes: new { id = "LSgrid" },
                    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
                    firstText: "<< First",
                    previousText: "< Prev",
                    nextText: "Next >",
                    lastText: "Last >>",

                    columns: grid.Columns(

                                grid.Column("ID", header: "", format:  @<text>@item.ID</text>, style: "colID"),
                                grid.Column("PathUse", header: "Image", format: @<text>
                                @if (item.PicType == "Color") 
                                {<img class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="100" src="@Url.Content(@item.PathToSave)" />}
                                 else
                                {<img class="img-thumbnail" width="100" height="100" src="@Url.Content(@item.PathToSave)" />}</text>, style: "colPath"),

                                grid.Column("DesignNo", header: "DesignNo", format: @<text>@item.Design_No</text>, style: "colDesignNo"),
                                grid.Column("StyleNo", header: "StyleNo", format: @<text>@item.Prod_No</text>, style: "colStyleNo"),
                                grid.Column("PageNo", header: "PageNo", format:@<input id="valPageNo" type="text" value="@item.Seq_No" />, style: "colPageNo"),
                                grid.Column("Position", header: "Position", format:@<input id="valPosition" type="text" value="@item.Seq_Position" /> , style: "colPosition"),
                                                                 grid.Column("Status", header: "Status", format: @<text>@item.Status </text>, style: "colStatus")
                   )
            )
```

Comment: Try to trim() text, maybe there is some empty space?

Comment: Could you also please share a sample of your table? I'm assuming adding CSS classes to your cells is not an option, correct? :-D

Comment: "When the value is 'Canceled'" - is it though? I mean is the type and value the same?

Comment: @TonyM : I used the alert to check the value and it is 'Canceled'.

Answer (score 0):

After numerous tries, I did the ultimate fix :

1. Closed Visual Studio and re-started.

This didnt work - so I simply restarted my computer and all is well! Not sure what happened there! 
Thanks everyone for your kind help.